# Barcode scan ingredient alias sorting

Tags: barcode, scanning

I work for an app that allows barcode scanning to load ingredients into a database. A problem we are having is that there are numerous alias' for the same ingredient. For example, a plant might have all these different alias':

```
JOJOBA OIL
JOJOBA OIL (BUXUS CHINENSIS)
JOJOBA OIL (HYDROGENATED)
JOJOBA OILS
JOJOBA OIL (SIMMONDSIA CHINENSIS)
JOJOBA OIL (SIMONDSIA CHINENSIS)
JOJOBA SEED EXTRACT
(JOJOBA) SEED OIL
JOJOBA SEED OIL
JOJOBA SEED OIL]
JOJOBASEED OIL
JOJOBA SEED OILJOJOBA
JOJOBA SEED OIL (JOJOBA)
JOJOBA SEED OIL (SIMMONDSIA CHINENSIS)
JOJOBA SEED POWDER
JOJOBA (SIMMONDSIA CHINENSIS) EXTRACT (REPLENISHING COMPLEX)
JOJOBA (SIMMONDSIA CHINENSIS)OIL
JOJOBA (SIMMONDSIA CHINENSIS) OIL
JOJOBA (SIMMONDSIA CHINENSIS) OIL (SAPONIFIED)
JOJOBA (SIMMONDSIA CHINENSIS) SEED OIL
JOJOBA WAX (BUXUS CHINENSIS)
JOJOBO SEED OIL
```

All of these alias' would be linked to the same ingredient but most of the time, we have to manually add it. With plants, there is no standardized way to name them so it is often found with many different alias'. If there a way we could use part of the name to automatically link the ingredient, that would be great. 
Thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 0):

It’s hard to recommend something without knowing which technologies you are targeting or what data you already have.  From your sample data it looks like your possible matches have the same prefix (if you normalize the data to remove parenthesis).

If you are working with application code you can construct a deterministic acyclic finite state automaton (sometimes also called a DAWG).  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_acyclic_finite_state_automaton)  This would allow you to perform prefix (or infix with a little tweaking) searches extremely fast.  You can combine a string metric (like Levenshtein Distance) to allow for misspellings or slight differences between ingredient names.  Steve Hanov has a great series of blog posts on tries and DAWGs.  Here is the post about DAWGs (http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=115).

I have successfully used this technique to find matches in millions of records with sub-second performance.

If you are looking for a database approach most DBMS's have a CONTAINS function that operates on a full-text index.

Perhaps if you provide a little more information we could provide a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

No doubt you have a table with individual ingredient names as key. Simply add to this table a column "ingredient cross-reference".

Whenever you add a new ingredient, simply set "ingredient cross-reference" to a new positive number **and** report the addition, so you may get (record#:Ingredient:cross-reference)

```
127 JOJOBA OIL      21
311 JOJOBA OILS     57
```

for instance. Decide on what your "standard" name will be, and change the cross-reference number to (- the standard's number)

```
127 JOJOBA OIL      21
311 JOJOBA OILS     -21
```

Then, whenever you locate "JOJOBA OILS", since the cross-reference is negative, you can locate the standard name by obvious means.

This can be extended. For instance, it's possible that you could have the same ingredient being called different things in different markets - national or even regional. For instance, in Australia, a "Capsicum" is what in the US is a "Bell Pepper"

You simply enter into your main table

```
551 Capsicum         32
306 Bell Pepper      -32
```

And in an auxiliary table of region:usage:reference

```
US               32      306
Aus              32      551
```

**if** there is an entry in this preferences table, then for ingredient with abs(cross-reference) 32 then use record 306 for the US market or 551 for the Australian market. **If** there is no entry, then the two markets use the same term.

(but seems to be more about database design than barcode-scanning...)